# Converting an DataFrame from pandas to dask

Tags: python, pandas, dask, partition, chunks

I followed this documentation  [dask.dataframe.from_pandas](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html?highlight=from_pandas#dask.dataframe.from_pandas) and there are optional arguments called `npartitions` and `chunksize`.

So I try write something like this:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(...)
df = dd.from_pandas(data=df)
```

And it raise error with that message:
`ValueError: Exactly one of npartitions and chunksize must be specified.`

I wondering how to solve it, How should I calculate the `npartitions` or `chunksize` of DataFrame like Dask doing while calling `dask.dataframe.read_csv`?

Comment: There is a formula to calculate one of them?

Answer (score 2):

You need to either choose `npartitions` (number of partitions) or `chunksize` (size of each partition) before your Dask dataframe can be built. You need to decide either how many parallel dataframes you want to split your pandas dataframe into or how large you want each parallel dataframe to be. Ideally you want to decide this based on how much memory your system has as well as how many cores it has available.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to provide either npartitions or chunksize.
In my case I tried both case and it worked well. But when I am specifying both the arguments it give me the same error.

So, specifying one of the two will clear the error.

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
dd_df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=100)
```

or

```py
dd_df =dd.from_pandas(df, chunksize=100)
```

Comment: How does this answer add anything beyond the already existing answers?

Answer (score 0):

May be it is a glitch in DASK ... because error itself says that we need to specify `npartitions(The number of partitions of the index to create)` or `chunksize(The number of rows per index partition to use.)` ..

**see this error** -

```
if (npartitions is None) == (chunksize is None):
   raise ValueError("Exactly one of npartitions and chunksize must be specified.")
```

here are best practices for `chunksize` and `npartitions` in dask dataframes

[ref 1](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/best-practices.html) ,   [ref 2](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-best-practices.html)